# Create a program that alters the execution of a windows application

Tags: windows

I have a windows application which has several sub-forms. i have to navigate through 5 or 6 forms to reach the form i need. this is time consuming since i have to open it several times through the day and i do it daily.

my need: i dont have the source project for this application, i got it as an executable program, but i need to create some application that does these steps for me automatically. In other words i need to find a way to automatically click the buttons that navigate through the forms and opens the form i need from step one.

is there any way i can do this ?

Comment: would appreciate if u tell me the reason for down voting to learn for the future :)

Comment: Possibly the beginning text that appears when you hover over the downvote symbol: "This question does not show any research effort..." explains the downvotes.

Comment: There are third party applications already available that will automate interaction with windows applications. Google "auto click windows program".

Comment: ok thank you for your reply, yes i didnt research because i didnt know im looking for exactly. your comment is helpful thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed, though generic solutions already exist to perform just this kind of function to arbitrary programs.

You can use Spy++ or a resource-editor, like ResHack or ResEdit to look at the program and get the control ids of the navigation buttons.

Once done, you can get a handle to the program itself and then send messages to it's `WindowProcedure` that would be generated if the user clicked the controls with a mouse,

Another alternative, is to get the position of the running target application, after you've got it's `HWND`, by using the `GetWindowRect` function. You could then use this position along with vert/horiz distances to generate mouse events.

The two have more-or-less the same result, though some applications won't work with approach #1.

In one instance, you need to use Spy++ to get the control IDs.
In the other instance, you need to use an image editor to get the pixel offsets of the controls.
In both instances, you'll need to use `FindWindow`, along with the window's title-text in order to get a `HWND` handle.

You could use a combination of the two - asking the program itself with `GetDlgItem` for the handle of the controls you need to click. You could then query the control for its position, before using `mouse_event` to position the mouse above it and again to click it.
Quite a few ways to skin this cat, actually.

Pre-existing solutions like AutoIt are said to be very easy to use and will be much easier than coding a new program for each target.